# Concatenate two columns, from two separate tables and insert into db using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app that I am currently migrating the db.

Previously they had two tables: Users and Companies

Within Users there is a subdomain entry and within companies there is a domain_name entry.

I created a new table called sites and am now trying to have one column called site_name that is subdomain.domain_name.

I know how to accomplish this with just Ruby, but it would be really slow to convert all of our users.

Would I be able to do something like:

`execute("UPDATE sites s SET s.site_name=(SELECT sub_domain FROM users WHERE user_id=s.user_id) + '.' + (SELECT domain_name FROM companies WHERE user_id=s.user_id)")`

EDIT:

Here is the updated problem.

I now have an additional table.

```
users
  |_ id
  |_ email
  |_ sub_domain

companies
  |_ id
  |_ domain_name

sites
  |_ id
  |_ site_name

user_sites
  |_ id
  |_ user_id
  |_ site_id
```

sites is the new table that I am creating and want to migrate the full domain to. I am having trouble creating a join that goes through the user_sites table. Here is roughly what I have come up with that is unsuccessful.

```
UPDATE
  sites s
INNER JOIN user_sites us ON s.id=us.site_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a.id, concat(a.sub_domain, '.', b.domain_name) site_address
FROM
  users as a
INNER JOIN companies as b ON a.company_id=b.id ) t ON t.id=us.user_id
SET
  s.site_name = t.site_address
```

EDIT 2:

Part of my problem was that I was trying to use UPDATE to create new rows.

Here is the approach I took towards moving the data from the users and companies table:

I start by creating rows in user_sites by adding the user_id to every user_site

```
INSERT INTO user_sites (user_id) SELECT id FROM users;
```

Then I create as many rows in sites as there are users

```
INSERT INTO sites (domain_name) SELECT id FROM users;
```

Afterwards I set the site_id in user_sites

```
UPDATE user_sites us
INNER JOIN users u ON us.user_id=u.id
INNER JOIN sites s ON s.domain_name=u.id
SET site_id=s.id WHERE us.user_id=u.id
```

Now, the part that fails is updating the domain name with the concat domain name

```
UPDATE sites s
    INNER JOIN
    user_sites us ON s.id=us.site_id
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.id, concat(a.wp_username, '.', b.domain_name) site_address
    FROM users as a
    INNER JOIN
    white_labels as b ON a.white_label_id=b.id
    ) t ON t.id = us.user_id
    SET domain_name=site_address
```

Everything works except the last domain part. The domains are all nil when I check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql you could use a update joined  with a table based on select for tables joined

```
    UPDATE sites s
    INNER JOIN ( 
    select a.user_id, concat(a.sub_domain, '.', b.domain_name) united_name
    FROM users as a
    INNER JOIN companies as b on a.user_id= b.user_id ) t on t.user_id = s.user_id 
    SET s.site_name  = t.united_name
```

Comment: The problem now requires a join table. I tried to use your logic to add an additional inner join to account for it, but I was unsuccessful. I updated the question to make what I am trying to do more clear.

Comment: What do you mean for "unsuccessful"  .. you have and error?  wrong? result?  no result ?

Comment: With the SQL I ended the question with, it will run (I am running it in a rails migration file), but it returns nil and doesn't actually appear to do anything.

Comment: your query seems right .. so try check the data you use for test  .. eventually updated  you question  . with a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: If the users and companies tables are populated, but the user_sites and sites tables are brand new. Would this create a new entry for every new site_name into the sites table? I got so caught up in moving the data that I overlooked the fact that one table is empty.

Comment: This query update  existining rows .. for create new entry you should use insert ..

Comment: Okay, so I updated it to use insert. I have everything setting up how I want it to, except the domain_name. It shows up as nil. I edited the post to show what I have so far.

Comment: be careful in your second insert  you are assigning  to domain_name  the id from users ..  ..

Comment: That was intentional for a reason omitted from this question. Thank you so much for all the help. I understand SQL queries much more after your help.